# netlogo - radial direction of the turtle

Tags: netlogo, shapes, heading

I have an ellipse shape. (created having vertical direction)
I want to place several such shapes on the circle contour
They should be placed having same distance one from another

```
;x,y - circle center coordinates
;r - radius
to draw-ellipses [x y r elNum ]
  if  elNum > 0 [
    let theta 0
    let delta 360 / elNum
    loop[
      if  elNum = 0 [ stop ]
      crt 1 [
        setxy (x + r * cos theta) (y + r * sin theta)
        set shape "ellipse"
        set heading 90 + theta
        set size 7
      ]
      set theta  (theta + delta)
      set elNum (elNum - 1)
    ]
  ]
end
```

The ellipse shapes ate placed correctly but their direction is wrong. I want the ellipses to have radial direction. I.e to be the continues of the radius to the point, where shape is placed. but directions are not good. 
Only for 0 and 180 degrees the directions are ok.

Some advices what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do I understand correctly that you want your turtles to face away from the radius? If that's true, try replacing your heading line with:

```
set heading atan xcor ycor
```

to do it in a way that is consistent with your angle math. Alternatively, you can use `facexy`, and replace the heading line instead with something like:

```
facexy x y
rt 180
```